# Serve Storybook as part of Next.js build/Vercel deployment

Tags: next.js, vercel, storybook

I have a Next.js (v14) application with Storybook (v7.6). I'd like to deploy it using Vercel so that '/' serves the Next.js build and '/storybook/' serves the Storybook build.

I tried customizing the Vercel config, but my free tier account does not permit concurrent builds.

Then I tried using [Next.js rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites) to no avail. And [this similar issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/16625) is out of date (deprecated config properties).

Anybody have experience doing this with Next.js 13 or 14? Any suggestions?